# Latex book odd page is coming with big right margin

Tags: books, book-design

I am writing my thesis using the `book` document class. The sample code is located on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/neel.basu/thesis-sample) project. The problem is each chapter starts on an odd page and the odd page has big right margin. I think the odd pages are printed on the front side of every page and the even pages are on the back side of the same page. So for the odd page the left margin should be bigger instead. Otherwise it will be problematic at the time of binding.
[image]

I start the `main.tex` with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
```

I use a custom style `justyle` to design the chapter headers, and the title page. But even when the justyle is not used I get the same margin.

**How can I make the odd pages the front side (i.e. left margin bigger) ?**

**Is what I am trying to do, the opposite of how it should be printed ? I mean is it already generating a binder friendly pdf that I am misinterpreting ?**

Even when I use `book` documentclass without any custom style then also the output is same.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, citestyle=alphabetic, backend=biber, url=false, doi=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction} % Main chapter title
\label{chap:introduction} % Change X to a consecutive number; for referencing this chapter elsewhere, use \ref{ChapterX}
\blindtext[12]

\chapter{Related Works} % Main chapter title
\label{chap:related}
\blindtext[12]

 \chapter{Conclusion}
\label{chap:conclusion}
\blindtext[12]

\backmatter

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

When I print the document, it looks like this. In the picture page 2 and page 3 are side by side. page 2 is on the left. See the size of the right margin of page 2 is different from the left margin of page 3.

[image]

Comment: this is a FAQ, the outer margins are larger by design. The margins are for placing your hands, and the inner margis are roughly half the outer ones so the two together look more even

Comment: you can use the geometry package to specify a binding offset to take in to account before the margins calculated

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No my odd pages are on the left side.

Comment: Exactly how do you see odd pages on the left? Which Pdf viewer? A lot of PDF viewers show side-by-side wrong (as can be seen in your image), page 1 always go on the right. I think Adobe Reader shows this in the wrong way, confusing a lot of users

Comment: latex doesn't control your printer the odd pages are designed for the right hand side, you need to force a blank at the start or adjust your printer settings so if you print on both sides they stack correctly

Comment: @daleif Whichever viewer I use, If I do both side printing then the page 1 is printed on the front side. page 2 is printed on the back of it. The thesis is bound on the left side but the extra space is on the right. I am using Okular BTW. However with this extra page it seems like the page 1 will be perfectly okay if printed on the back of some other page (Hence it will be on the left).

Comment: The large margin is *not* for the binding. It is large on the outside, because on the inside there are two margins (from the left and the right page).  The binding correction is something different and can be set additionally.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But why is the large margin on the right side of page 1 and on the left side of the page 2. If the page 1 is on the front then shouldn't it be exactly opposite ? Because the page 2 will be printed on the back side of page 1.

Comment: Get a real book, open it. Then check which margin of an odd page is on the outside and which on the inside.

Comment: The large margin on the outside has two traditional purposes: (1) so that your thumbs don't obscure the text when you are holding the book, and (2) to allow space for writing notes, a long-standing scholarly tradition.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: @NeelBasu: Do you have any zoom specification/scaling set when printing? Printing it with a fit-to-page is perhaps an option to choose.